# How to render custom street maps

Tags: maps

This is sort of a two part question.

First off, how can I render my own maps? Google, Bing, etc. seem to provide their own renderings that are effectively images, or so I understand. However, my objective is to be able to just get the data for streets and create my own representation from that data.

The second part is where and how can I get this information? Everywhere I look I find information on how to embed a map from Google, Bing, or whomever else.

If there is a resource that answers one, the other, or both parts, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two quick answers: [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org/) and [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/).

OpenStreetMap is the only significant worldwide source of openly licensed street data. Some countries have their own sources - for example, in the US you can use the US Census Bureau's [TIGER](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/opendata-products.html) data (which is of very variable quality), or in the UK you can use [Ordnance Survey OpenData](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/opendata-products.html) - and if your needs are restricted to one country, that might be fine. Even so, OSM's community-created data tends to be much richer than that of national mapping agencies, though in some areas it might lack completeness.

OSM's [full-planet data](http://planet.osm.org/) is a vast file and you'll need fairly serious hardware to process it, but country and regional extracts are available (for free) from third-party providers such as [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/).

Mapnik is the standard rendering software, capable of 2D rendering the equal of major webmapping sites (Google etc.). It's often used as part of a package called [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) which provides a CSS-like styling language.

You can find out more about the full toolchain, and the basics of OSM rendering, at the [switch2osm.org](http://switch2osm.org/) tutorial site.

Comment: Thank you, Richard. I will have to take a closer look into MapNik, and the Open OSM is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)?  They're mostly a repository for open-source map data (street layouts etc.), but the project links to renderers for their mapping data which might give you a start towards creating your own.